# How to build a regression equation in power bi from model summary?

Tags: powerbi

How to build the regression equation from the model coefficient to do a sort of what-if analysis as in where if u increase the value of X variable how will it affect Y variable

[Model Summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npKh4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Regression can be of many form having different kinds of equations. Basic linear regression can have this kind of equation y = cX + a

Here
y is the dependent variable which we want to determine based on the value of X
c is co-efficient which indicates how strong the influence
a is constant

As you can see here you need to know the signed value of c, X and a in order to get the linear regression equation. You sample data set is missing all these value.

Again determining all these variable values and analyze their relations with one another is part of data analysis PowerBI can help you to represent those data and relations graphically.

Can get some more insight here....
https://statisticsbyjim.com/regression/predictions-regression/

Comment: i have uploaded the entire model summary the idea is to build a regression equation using coefficient value in the data in power bi